# Get name of taxonomies of current page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get the Taxonomy name the same way I get the term name: $term->name - Is this possible?

But $taxonomy->name does not display anything. $taxonomy alone displays the slug, but I want the label/name of the taxonomy.

```
// get taxonomies terms links
function custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
    global $post, $post_id;
    // get post by post id

    $post = &get_post( $post->ID );

    // get post type by post
    $post_type = $post->post_type;

    // get post type taxonomies
    $taxonomies    = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );
    $taxonomynames = get_queried_object();
    $out           = " <ul'>";

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $out .= "<li'><span'>" . $taxonomy->name . ": ";
        $out .= "</span>";

        // get the terms related to post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out .= '<a href="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
            }
        }

        $out .= "</li>";
    }

    $out .= "</ul>";

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_object_taxonomies` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/) only returns the slugs of all registered taxonomies to that post type, so you're almost there. You need to actually go get the taxonomy itself using [`get_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy)

```
...
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
    $out .= "<li'><span'>" . $tax_object->name . ": ";
    $out .= "</span>";
    ...
```